# Specifying root folder express-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, http, express, proxy

I am using [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy)

basic setup

```
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use('/api/', proxy(`http://api-url/`));

app.listen(3000);
```

works as expected, except static files. they are point to proxy host instead of proxy route

```
http://localhost:3000/bundle.js
```

it should be

```
http://localhost:3000/api/bundle.js
```

Comment: Is the bundle.js file on the proxy host or local? I assume you are requesting a html file or similar and within it it has a reference to bundle.js? You may have to use relative paths for this scenario to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that bundle.js is a file hosted on the proxy host. Wherever it is referenced you may have to use relative paths so that it does not go to the root of the url.